# how to simulate different browsers in jmeter load run?

Tags: cross-browser, jmeter, performance-testing

Is it possible to simulate a load run in different desktop browsers & their versions using Jmeter? I knew that by using "Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files" & "Use concurrent pool. Size=" options we can simulate a real browser but my requirement is to simulate a specific browser. If possible, could someone please provide the steps to achieve it?

Comment: Browser related information goes in Header manager. But I don't think it is equivalent of simulating the browser. You might find a solution by looking into using webdriver sampler (for JMeter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header with the value of browser you want to mimic.

You might also want to add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) and [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) in order to simulate browsers more closely.

Also consider using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) if you looking for a form of distribution, i.e. 60% Chrome, 20% Safari, etc. see [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for more details.

And remember, JMeter doesn't actually "render" the page, it downloads response as plain text so you won't be able to detect any rendering issues. It neither executes JavaScript.